# A CSS animation of a SVG Images 'fill' property not working in Safari

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to create a CSS animation for the fill color of a specific part of a SVG image. For that I'm using keyframes and an 'id' to link the animation and the SVG rectangle. You can see a working example here:

http://jsbin.com/deyaqo/3/

This works for most of the browsers except Safari (and maybe IE, I don't know). I'm not sure if this is because of my implementation or due to the lack of support from this vendor.

Thanks for your time !

Comment: Did you try using `animateColor` instead `@keyframes`?

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge, do you mean the SVG element ?

Comment: Yes the `svg` element.

Comment: I though they were going to deprecate it , am I wrong ? Let me check that It could be a good solution

Comment: Although is going to be [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateColor), maybe `animate`element could be a solution ?

Comment: animateColor is already deprecated. Use animate instead of animateColor always.

Comment: `animate`element is [not supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=SMIL) in IE :(

Comment: For IE you can use fakeSmile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `animate` element instead.

```html
<svg id="logo" x="0" y="0" width="150" viewBox="12.304 3.974 74.952 22.051" enable-background="new 12.304 3.974 74.952 22.051">
  <rect id="laukia"
        x="56.74"
        y="23.094"
        width="17.895"
        height="2.932"
        fill="black" />
  <animate xlink:href="#laukia"
           attributeType="XML"
           attributeName="fill"
           from="red" to="rosybrown"
           values="red; blue; green; teal; saddlebrown; peru; plum; rosybrown"
           repeatCount="indefinite"
           dur="5s" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you! nice one , How could I add IE support ?

Comment: As @Robert Longson pointed out, you could use [FakeSmile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/index.html) for IE support.